# SQL order subquery returning fatal error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the 24 most recent records and then order them in ascending order. It returns a 'fetch_assoc()' error when run.

```
$datasql = "SELECT HOUR(RecordDate) AS RecordHour, DATE(RecordDate) AS RecordDay, Count 
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM difc
                                    ORDER BY RecordID DESC
                                    LIMIT 24
                                )
                                ORDER BY RecordID";
                    $dataresult = $db->query($datasql);
                    while($row = $dataresult->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo $row["Count"];
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show the actual error?

Comment: Side note:  `SELECT *` should be avoided for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

every derived table must have a alias:

i have add **AS tmp**

```
$datasql = "SELECT HOUR(RecordDate) AS RecordHour, DATE(RecordDate) AS RecordDay, Count 
                                FROM (
                                    SELECT *
                                    FROM difc
                                    ORDER BY RecordID DESC
                                    LIMIT 24
                                ) AS tmp
                                ORDER BY RecordID";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, knew it was probably something quite simple. Only been coding SQL for about a week and still learning, thank you again.